# How to display a specific div on mouseover when I have n ids?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I'm trying to display a specific div when I have more (n) div with (n) ids. I have this code for example:

```
for($i=0;$i<=50;$i++){
echo '
    <div class="item-box"> 
        <div id="id'.$i.'" class="info-ishop">
            De la nivelul 105<br><br>
            Valoarea atacului: 234 - 244<br>
            Valoarea atacului magic : 433 - 543<br>
            Viteza de atac : 25% <br><br>
            Sloturi de piatră : 3<br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="item-box-img">
            <img src="../img/item/03090.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item-box-text">
            <h3> Arma mortală</h3>
            <div class="thems_line"></div>
            <p>Vândut de: 0 ori</p>
            <p>Preț: <font color="green"><b> 50 </b></font> MD</p>
            <form class="ishop-form">
                <button>Cumpără</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
';
}
```

When I mouseover the `item-box-img` class I want to display the div with class `info-ishop` and id "n"

I'm really blocked with this.. please help me and sorry for my English.

Comment: Please clarify. When you `mouseover` the div with class `item-box-img` you want to display WHICH div? The following one?

Comment: This div <div id="id'.$i.'" class="info-ishop"> sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved myself, with this code. Sorry for my answer here but this is the better way to view the resolve solution. i add this for div i need to mouseover and i echo the id in for loop

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('id<?php echo $i;?>').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('id<?php echo $i;?>').style.display = 'none';"


for($i=0;$i<=50;$i++){
 echo '
<div class="item-box"> 
           <div id="id'.$i.'" class="info-ishop">
                De la nivelul 105<br><br>
                Valoarea atacului: 234 - 244<br>
                Valoarea atacului magic : 433 - 543<br>
                Viteza de atac : 25% <br><br>
                Sloturi de piatră : 3<br><br>
            </div>
                <div class="item-box-img" onmouseover="document.getElementById("id'.$i.'").style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById("id'.$i.'").style.display = 'none';" ><img src="../img/item/03090.png"/></div>
                <div class="item-box-text">
                    <h3> Arma mortală</h3>
                    <div class="thems_line"></div>
                    <p>Vândut de: 0 ori</p>
                    <p>Preț: <font color="green"><b> 50 </b></font> MD</p>
                    <form class="ishop-form">
                        <button>Cumpără</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
           </div>
';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with css

```
.info-ishop{
    display:none;
}

.item-box:hover .info-ishop{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Ok, i know but i have more .info-ishop, with different value in this div.. and how to display one by one.. not all .

Comment: This should only display the .info-ishop in the item-box that you are hovering.  If that doesn't work you can look into using ul's.

Comment: In my for case , i echo the id0 id1 id2 id3 .. idn , and i want to display for this .. i don't know how many id is..